# How to calculate this Cross product

Tags: evaluation, vector

I was trying to calculate this Cross product

```
Cross[{a, b}, {c, d + e}]
```

Mathematica gives the following result

```
{a, b} x {c, d + e}
```

and below error information:

> Cross: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.

However, I would like to get the following result:

```
a d + a e - b c
```

How to do it?

Comment: Cross product of two vectors gives a vector orthogonal to them. If you have two 2D vectors, they are situated in a plane. An orthogonal vector should point out of plane. Thus, the whole problem is 3D, and therefore, you also need to provide 3D vectors as an input.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, cross product is unique for 3D vectors. Pad 0s to the vectors as their 3rd components before crossing them

```
Cross[{a, b, 0}, {c, d + e, 0}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, -b c + a d + a e}
> ```

and one can take the 3rd component of the result.

---

**Update**

One can also use [`TensorWedge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorWedge.html) without padding

```
TensorWedge[{a, b}, {c, d + e}][[1, 2]]
```

Comment: But I don't want to add the third coordinate of the vector. Why can't I do the calculation with two vector coordinates?

Comment: @SIJA OK, there is also another method without padding. See my update.

Comment: @SIJA Regarding your "why", as I have said, cross product is unique for 3D vectors (at some Mathematical level).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Also see an excellent understanding in the comment by @yarchik.